# Can I use a 30A backfeed breaker when I'm not using the generator?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, subpanel

I have a panel in my garage with a "Generator" 30A breaker. I know I shouldn't be backfeeding the generator (I inherited this setup and am scheduling an electrician to put in a transfer switch). Having said that, can I turn that 30A breaker on and use the 220v outlet that it goes to?

Comment: Is that breaker interlocked to the main so it can't be on when the main's on?  What make and model of panel is this by the way?

Comment: Don't put in one of those hokey Chinese transfer switches with like 6 switches, 1 for each circuit.  It is wiring spaghetti and a general disaster.  Better to use a subpanel of your chosen size, with the top 4 spaces occupied by backfed breakers with an onboard interlock (panel $60-150, breakers $10 each, interlock $30, Siemens makes a fine one). Then you move any mix of 120/240 circuits to the subpanel.

Comment: I much prefer the setup illustrated below - I have a generator input interlocked with the main of my 200A panel, and I can run any device on the panel without "getting creative" so long as I don't overload the generator (and it will tell me if I do.) Limited subpanels or transfer switches encourage unsafe "creativity" when some item not on them is deemed important during an outage. The only reason to have a transfer switch is if you need "autostart/autotransfer" and most of us really don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should be physically impossible, and the "outlet" should not be an outlet (it should be a boxed plug).

If it's physically possible and the outlet is an outlet, it's not a generator input unless you enjoy having your service terminated when the power company finds out about it. So remove any "generator" label, **take apart the suicide cord**, and use the outlet as an outlet.

It's quite possible to backfeed in a safe and correct manner with a listed manual interlock (the main OR the generator can be on, both can be off, but both cannot be on, by physical interlock preventing that) and a boxed-plug input to the backfeed breaker. You absolutely do not need a (generally overpriced) transfer switch.

This is a manual interlock for a Square-D QO panel - there are other styles for other panel types/brands.

[image: Manual interlock]

Here's a typical correct generator input, fed from an extension cord with a receptacle on the end that won't (easily) electrocute you.

[image: generator input plug]

Comment: This is the ideal way to do a transfer switch.  Also note this is a **reputable maker of service equipment**: Square D.  Eaton, Siemens, GE being others.

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into the manual interlock and... yes... not use the suicide cord. This must have been a DIY job that the previous owner did, I can't imagine any electrician setting this up for someone.

Comment: @darrickc it's possible no electrician set it up at all.  A NEMA 10-30 or 14-30 receptacle could meet your description, and that might already have been present for a dryer.