# How can I move the neutral-ground bond to my house from the pole?

Tags: electrical-panel, code-compliance

Suppose I have a setup like this: I take my power at a pole. The utility wants me to fit circuit protection there for a very long run to my house.

[image]

By my read of things, this makes it a *main panel* and therefore this is the primary grounding point.  And therefore the panel in the house is a subpanel.

Trying to answer [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/133706/cabin-wiring-plan-revisited), I found a NEC section (*Article* 310.15(B)(7) not to be confused with the *table* of the same number) which allows feeder in this case to be sized like service lateral, logical since it's doing the same job.

**I would really, really like to have the neutral-ground bond at the house instead of the pole**.

In my travels through NEC *I could swear* I saw a section that liberalizes where the N-G bond is in this case... and I thought might even permit omission of that long ground wire.   But I can't find it again.

Can anyone help me find it?

Comment: Install an isolation transformer then it would be a separately derived system and you could have the bond in the main panel. I don't remember being able to have the bond on a sub since the 99 code? Still looking. If there is a transformer at the pole 250.30.1 exception 2 might be close but I think it would still be a sub. In your case.

Comment: When you say "The utility wants me to fit circuit protection there for a very long run to my house." The utility will usually run the underground to your house for a price and it would then be considered the service lateral since the meter would then be mounted on the house. Around here, our utility charges $4 a foot last time I used them. A little over $1000 for your situation. The service disconnect is the main point of bonding. NEC 205.24(A)(5) prohibits connection after the service with limited exceptions. I don't think your situation is one of the exceptions.

Comment: @ArchonOSX the application location has a utility that is a little weird. To be plain, I'm lifting this question from that linked  question, because it's vexing me.  He was unable to get the utility to serve at the house.

Comment: @Harper -- out in the sticks, its actually rather common for the utility service to terminate at a pole on your property, with you responsible for bringing it the rest of the way to where it needs to go

Answer (score 1):

### Yes, but *only* if you have a single, non-fused switching means at the pole, not a panel

You can do this *if and only if* the switch at the pole is a single switching means (fault-rated, non-fused disconnect switch), not any sort of panelboard, enclosed breaker, or fused switch.  In this case, the switch at the pole becomes a *hot-sequence meter disconnect* (as opposed to the *service disconnecting means*), and is permitted by NEC 230.82(3):

> (3) Meter disconnect switches nominally rated not in excess of 1000V that have a short-circuit current rating equal to or greater than the available short-circuit current, provided that all metal housings and service enclosures are grounded in accordance with Part VII and bonded in accordance with Part V of Article 250.  A meter disconnect switch shall be capable of interrupting the load served.  A meter disconnect shall be legibly field marked on its exterior in a manner suitable for the environment as follows:
>
> ```
>                               METER DISCONNECT
>                             NOT SERVICE EQUIPMENT
> ```

This may require consultation with the AHJ and/or utility -- they may require such a disconnect to be installed *cold sequence* i.e. ahead of the meter instead.  This is normally only seen on socket-metered 480V services where yanking the meter out of its socket under load is a good way to get yourself roasted by arc flash, but nothing in the NEC *prohibits* a meter disconnect on a 120/240V service.

Answer (score 0):

This is along the lines of what ThreePhaseEel just posted. Note that I'm heavily paraphrasing from Ch. 17 Farm Wiring in Hartwell, Frederic P./ Richter, Herbert P./ Schwan, W. C. *Wiring Simplified: Based on the 2017 National Electrical Code.* Independent Pub Group, 2017.

In farm wiring it is common to install a meter on a pole (NEC "distribution point"). The neutral is grounded at the pole. The disconnecting means on the pole is termed a "site isolating device" to distinguish it from a service disconnect and the wiring leaving this device is service entrance wire conforming to the usual specifications.

We establish a service entrance at each building served directly from the distribution point. In the case of a (farm)house three-wire service would be the norm and the neutral is regrounded at the home as in a direct termination.

In higher amperage installations a current transformer is used to avoid running large wires down to the meter socket. The site-isolating switch can be double-throw to switch between the utility line and a generator.